# Mail send using no credentials C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, sendmail

everyone.
I need to send a No-reply mail using C#. Network admin told me that the SMTP server is configured to send  this type of mails (using any account without a password). I'm trying this:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential credencials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
credencials.UserName = "mail@domain.com";
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
mail.To.Add(email);
mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@domain.com");
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = message;
SmtpServer.Host = "smtpserver";
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.Credentials = credencials;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

I've tried without credentials, using Empty string as password, but nothing seems to work.

Am I forgetting  any special parameter or configuration?

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If so, could you add the exception message as well?

Comment: you can use SmtpClient to send the email messages.check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just a Simple: Cannot send email System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) , I tried to print the stacktrace too but it's the same exception. NOTE: My VS is in Spanish and I just translate the exception, the text may be different in English.

Comment: @user2426616 - Check the InnerException. It should contain more detailed information

Comment: Are you sure about using SSL on port 25? Normally port 465 is used with SSL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the combination of providing a username and using SSL on port 25 means authentication is tried but fails and the wrong protocol negotiation is attempted.  If you change your code the following what then happens?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
mail.To.Add(email);
mail.From = new MailAddress("mail@domain.com");
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = message;
SmtpServer.Host = "smtpserver";
SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
try {
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception Inner:   " + ex.InnerException);
}
```

I am assuming here that the server you are trying to use supports mail relay without authentication, which should rule out any sane configuration on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this is the Exception:
The remote name could not be resolved: 'relaysmtp.xxx.xxx'
I don't  know if this is because of a problem in the network or simply I dont have access to the mail server.

Comment: @user2426616 - it means it can't turn the FQDN you have given into the IP address of the server.  Try first using the IP of the server, then work back.

Comment: Thanks man, your solution seems useful, let me try it and I'll be posting back.

Comment: I used the IP instead of the  FQDN and it works. Thank you, you saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line to see what error you receive after the change:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = credencials;
```

Minimize the amount of properties you set. I think the minimum you need is to instantiate smtpclient and mailmessage.

Minimum:

```
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpserver");
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
```

set the:
mail.To
mail.From
mail.Subject
mail.Body

```
smtp.Send(mail);
```